# Ignor XML tags inside element value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the next element

```
<statement id ="5">
       insert into TBTEMPLATES(CTDB_LAST_UPDATOR) values('<?xml version="1.0"     encoding="UTF-8"?><Interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="%s"><Change><ChangeRequest/></Change></Interface>');
</statement>
```

I want to print the value of that node as is it ,despite what i tried , i face this  error always.

Unable to get the file C:\test\test1.xml-restable.xml for the XSL transformation.
Error: Character 'x' is grammatically unexpected

Could any one help me.

Comment: This is invalid .xml file. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CDATA block http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

```
<statement id ="5"><![CDATA[
       insert into TBTEMPLATES(CTDB_LAST_UPDATOR) values('<?xml version="1.0"     encoding="UTF-8"?><Interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="%s"><Change><ChangeRequest/></Change></Interface>');
]]></statement>
```